# convert sql server stored procedure to MySQL(xampp)

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am trying to implement a procedure within mysql(**XAMPP**). Thing is i have written my stored procedure in **SQL SERVER** I am not sure if this is an appropriate situation for a migrating to **phpmyadmin** but it should be converted to **xampp** and I apologize if this is extremely simple but this is my first run at procedures.

If somebody could please tell me what should i do so, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks! Here is my **sql server** stored procedure

```
BEGIN TRAN
GO
GO
create PROC calcPro
(
@p_Date DATE 

)
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO calcula (PID) 
SELECT PID FROM products WHERE PID NOT IN (SELECT PID FROM calcula)

CREATE TABLE  #tmpCalc-- IF NOT EXISTs-->
(
PID INT, Date1 DATE, Date2 DATE,SaleDate DATE,[Days] INT,total_days int,depreciation NUMERIC(20,2), 
depcur_value NUMERIC(20,2),next_diffdays int,salestatus int, FLAG CHAR(1)
)
INSERT INTO #tmpCalc (PID, Date1, Date2,total_days,depreciation,SaleDate,salestatus)
SELECT A.pid, A.added_date, @p_Date, c.category_life, A.depre, sale_Date, A.sale_status
FROM products A, calcula B,categories c
WHERE A.pid=B.pid and a.cid=c.cid

UPDATE #tmpCalc SET [Days]=datediff(dd,Date1,Date2)

UPDATE #tmpCalc SET [Days]=0,next_diffdays=datediff(dd,Date1,SaleDate) where [Days] <0 
--UPDATE #tmpCalc SET next_diffdays=0 where Date1 < '2018-03-31' 

UPDATE #tmpCalc SET depcur_value=((CONVERT(numeric(20,2),depreciation)/total_days)*[Days])

--UPDATE #tmpCalc SET wtvalue=((CONVERT(numeric(20,2),b.depre)/c.category_life)*a.[Days])
--FROM #tmpCalc A, products B, categories C
--WHERE A.pid=b.pid and b.cid=c.cid

UPDATE calcula SET yEnd=A.[Days],rem_days = A.total_days - [Days],cur_depre = A.depcur_value,cur_wrvalue = A.depreciation-A.depcur_value
FROM #tmpCalc A, calcula B
WHERE A.pid=B.pid

UPDATE calcula SET yEnd=0,rem_days=0,cur_wrvalue =0 WHERE yEnd <= 0

DECLARE @SaleDt INT, @YendDt INT, @L_PID INT, @Date2 DATE, @DepValue1 NUMERIC(20,2), @DepValue2 NUMERIC(20,2), 
@DepValue NUMERIC(20,2)

SELECT @SaleDt=COUNT(*) FROM calcula WHERE sale_status='1'
SELECT @YendDt=COUNT(*) FROM calcula WHERE sale_status='0'


WHILE @SaleDt > 0
    BEGIN

        SELECT @L_PID=PID,@Date2=Date1 FROM #tmpCalc WHERE salestatus='1' AND FLAG IS NULL

        SELECT @DepValue1=A.depreciation,@DepValue2=B.cur_wrvalue FROM #tmpCalc A, calcula B WHERE A.PID=B.pid AND A.PID=@L_PID

        IF @DepValue2='0'
            BEGIN
                SET @DepValue=@DepValue1
            END
        ELSE
        IF @DepValue2!='0'
            BEGIN
                SET @DepValue=@DepValue2
            END

        IF @Date2<='2018-03-31'
            BEGIN
                SET @Date2='2018-04-01'
            END

        UPDATE #tmpCalc SET next_diffdays=datediff(dd,@Date2,SaleDate) where pid=@L_PID
        UPDATE calcula SET next_wtvalue=(@DepValue-next_depre) where pid=@L_PID

        SET @SaleDt=@SaleDt-1
        UPDATE #tmpCalc SET FLAG='Y' WHERE PID=@L_PID
        SET @L_PID=''
        SET @Date2=''
        SET @DepValue2='0'
        SET @DepValue1='0'
        SET @DepValue='0'

    END


WHILE @YendDt > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @L_PID=PID,@Date2=Date1 FROM #tmpCalc WHERE salestatus='0' AND FLAG IS NULL

        SELECT @DepValue1=A.depreciation,@DepValue2=B.cur_wrvalue FROM #tmpCalc A, calcula B WHERE A.PID=B.pid AND A.PID=@L_PID

        IF @DepValue2='0'
            BEGIN
                SET @DepValue=@DepValue1
            END
        ELSE
        IF @DepValue2!='0'
            BEGIN
                SET @DepValue=@DepValue2
            END

        IF @Date2<='2018-03-31'
            BEGIN
                SET @Date2='2018-04-01'
            END

        UPDATE #tmpCalc SET next_diffdays=datediff(dd,@Date2,'2019-03-31') where pid=@L_PID
        UPDATE calcula SET next_wtvalue=(@DepValue-next_depre) where pid=@L_PID

        SET @YendDt=@YendDt-1
        UPDATE #tmpCalc SET FLAG='Y' WHERE PID=@L_PID
        SET @L_PID=''
        SET @Date2=''
        SET @DepValue2='0'
        SET @DepValue1='0'
        SET @DepValue='0'
    END

UPDATE calcula SET next_depre = (A.depreciation/A.total_days) * A.next_diffdays,accumdepre=b.cur_depre+b.next_depre
FROM #tmpCalc A, calcula B
WHERE A.pid=B.pid




SELECT * FROM #tmpCalc 
--select p.pid,c.pid,p.product_name,p.depre,c.yEnd,c.rem_days,c.cur_depre from products p,calcula c where p.pid = c.pid
select * from calcula
END
GO
EXEC calcPro '2018-03-31'
GO
  --select * from calcula
  --select * from products
  --select * from categories
GO
--ROLLBACK TRAN
commit
```

Comment: You can follow these tutorials: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx ; and try to convert your existing procedure. Once done, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53225706/edit) the question to add your latest attempt. Thanks :)

Comment: Every relational database has it's own way of writing stored procedures. What works in sql server will (usually) not work in mysql, oracle or postgresql

Comment: Yes i know it won't work so that only posted to seek some help to migrate this code as per my sql. Thanks for your time

Comment: I would recommend you take a stab at it and if you run into a problem with the MySQL proc then post a question about the specific problem you have.

Comment: Porting stored procedure and stored-function code from one DBMS to another is no trivial task. It takes knowledge of both DBMSs' query and programming languages. Imparting that knowledge to you is far beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer. If I were you I'd allocate at least a whole week to do the task in your question (IF you already understand the application).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to change a store procedure from MSSQL to MySQL, you should inspect the whole script taking into account the sintax changes that exists between the two languages.

Looking to your SP, here are some things that need to be change to make it work in MySQL (there are probably more):

**Create the SP with:**

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE calcPro()
BEGIN
  ...
END//
```

You have to use `DELIMITER` to avoid unexpected syntax erros. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

**The creation of temporary tables is different in MySQL:**

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpCalc (PID INT,....)
```

**The `UPDATE ... FROM ...` syntax is not valid in MySQL**, you should try something like:

```
UPDATE calcula B, #tmpCalc A
  SET yEnd=A.[Days]
      ,rem_days = A.total_days - [Days]
      ,cur_depre = A.depcur_value
      ,cur_wrvalue = A.depreciation-A.depcur_value
WHERE A.pid=B.pid
```

**Setting variables:**

One variable:

```
SET @SaleDt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM calcula WHERE sale_status='1');
```

Multiple variables:

```
SELECT PID, Date1
INTO   @L_PID, @Date2
FROM #tmpCalc
WHERE salestatus='1'
  AND FLAG IS NULL;
```

**The `WHILE` syntax is different.** Check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/while.html

```
WHILE @SaleDt > 0 DO
  ...
END WHILE;
```

**Even executing the SP is different:**

```
CALL calcPro('2018-03-31');
```

Comment: thanq so much Freddy for spending your valuable time.